# Excel VBA copy range and cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data from Sheet A into Sheet B.

I want to copy a range of cells from row 4 to row 13 of column X (X=column of cell with the highest value of row 13, and paste the copied values into row 4 to row 13 of sheet B.

Running the code does not copy the data, I get no errors but nothing gets pasted.

Can someone please take a look at the code to see where my mistake is:

```
Sub Daily()
    Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
    Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
    Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
    Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
    Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
    Dim CheckForDups As Range ' Used to find duplicate dates on the record Sheet
    Dim maxCustomerCnt As Double ' value of highest customer count



    Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet A")
    Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet B")
    With recordSht
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    End With
    With dailySht
        lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
        maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(13, 1), .Cells(13, lColDaily))), 2)
        Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(13, 1), .Cells(13, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
        ' Check the Record Sheet to ensure the data is not already there
            Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(13, 1), recordSht.Cells(13, lCol)).Find(What:=Round(maxCustomerRng.Value, 2), LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' If CheckForDups is Nothing then the date was not found on the record sheet. Therefore, copy the column
            If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(4, maxCustomerRng), Cells(13, maxCustomerRng)).Copy
                recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            End If
        End If
    End With

    Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
    Set dailySht = Nothing
    Set recordSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code (Use F8)?  My guess is you have both or the initial if statement giving a false, which ends the statement.  Helps narrow down the issue, and also lets you see what values are being pulled for each variable.

Comment: @Cyril Actually the code used to work fine when copying the entire column. I'm trying to modify it to copy only specific cells, this is where I'm getting problems. So I think the issue is with the copy/paste functions. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to find a rounded value in a set of unrounded data. CheckForDups is always nothing

Comment: I think the issue is with the copy and paste functions. The code was working fine when copying the entire column instead of specific cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

> ```
> With dailySht
> ```

And then these implicit references to the `ActiveSheet` within that `With` block:

> ```
> Range(Cells(4, maxCustomerRng), Cells(13, maxCustomerRng)).Copy
> ```

These implicit `ActiveSheet` references make your code work *depending on which worksheet is currently active*, which is likely not what you intended - FWIW [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) can help you easily find them everywhere they are in your project:

[image: Rubberduck inspections]

The solution is likely to *qualify* these calls with a dot, so that they work off the `dailySht` worksheet object:

```
.Range(.Cells(4, maxCustomerRng), .Cells(13, maxCustomerRng)).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks but the code is linked to a button on the recordSht button so I guessing that shouldn't be an issue?